# Django debug toolbar conflicts with jquery UI

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, conflict, django-debug-toolbar

In the template I import jquery, jqueryUI and java script code that creates a dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/my_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bla" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized
    and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The contents of my_script.js:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#bla" ).dialog();
});
```

The dialog shows up, and debug toolbar is visible but when I click the 'close' button of the dialog, debug toolbar dissapears as well. Also, when I click any panel nothing happens.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: did you try changing the classnames being used to something else? may be that is conflicting. I have never faced this issue, and I use both extensively.

Comment: You have complete example, what classnames am I using? "bla" here is an ID, ID is unique. Anyway, I don't think such a name is used in django-toolbar.